# regular expression (regex) of end of the string

Tags: regex, linux, bash, shell

I want to add the symbols related to the end of the string in my regexp

```
echo aaa.bbb.ccc=3 | grep  "aaa\.[^.]\+\.ccc=3"
```

I tried the following symbols but it does not works

```
echo aaa.bbb.ccc=3 | grep  "aaa\.[^.]\+\.ccc=3\Z"
echo aaa.bbb.ccc=3 | grep  "aaa\.[^.]\+\.ccc=3$/"
```

How I can add end of string symbol to my regexp?

**Update**

question 2)

```
echo aaa.bbb.ccc=3 | grep  "aaa\.[^.]\+\.ccc=3"
#                                             ^
#                                             |
#           What symbols I have to add here in order to say I m expecting end of string or any thing except the digits [^0-9]?
```

Comment: @ruifeng that's it thank you. please add it as answer and I will accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `echo aaa.bbb.ccc=3 | grep  "aaa\.[^.]\+\.ccc=3$"`

Answer 2:

Use `echo aaa.bbb.ccc=3 | grep  "aaa\.[^.]\+\.ccc=3[^0-9]*"`

`[^0-9]*` will include `$` also.

Refer **[Understanding Regular Expressions](http://www.robelle.com/smugbook/regexpr.html#grep)** for more details.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I updated my question I add a new query could you please see it

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
\($\|[^0-9]\)
```

to match either the end of input or a non-digit character.